# Appending values to array in a class?

Tags: php, oop

####update:
i have a curl connection method which has an array to set options and i need to append an option in the listDirectory method and send it to the first method (connection)

I would like to append the values in method two to the array in method one
and when I call method one, I would like to display:

```
Array ( [one] => 111 [two] => 2222[three] => 3333)
```

Can anyone help?

```
<?php

class test{
   
   public $myarray;
   
   public function one(){
      
     return $this->myarray=array(
      "one"=>"111",
      "two"=>"222"
      );
      
   }
   
   public function two(){
      
      return $this->myarray["three"]="333";
   }
}
$myclass=new test();
$myclass->one();
$myclass->two();


print_r($myclass->one());
```

Comment: There's no question or problem statement here

Comment: `$myarray` is only available inside the method's scopes. You want `$this->myarray`

Comment: done but no difference

Comment: `print_r($myclass->one());` will always return the array you defined in that `one()` method. You want to `print_r($myclass->myarray);`

Comment: actually its example i need to append a value in  method two to the array in method one which i will use it to process something (connection)...so i need to print method one and use it like this

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I don't know exactly what you need. I think something like this:

```
class test{
   
   public $myarray = [];
   
   public function add(array $array = []){
     return $this->myarray = array_merge($this->myarray, $array);    
   }

   public function get(){
     return $this->myarray;
   }
}

$myclass=new test();

$arr0 = $myclass->get();
// array(0) { }

$arr1 = $myclass->add(["one"=>"111","two"=>"222"]);  
//array(2) { ["one"]=> string(3) "111" ["two"]=> string(3) "222" }

$arr2 = $myclass->add(["three" =>"333"]); 
//array(3) { ["one"]=> string(3) "111" ["two"]=> string(3) "222" ["three"]=> string(3) "333" } 

$arr4 = $myclass->get();
//array(3) { ["one"]=> string(3) "111" ["two"]=> string(3) "222" ["three"]=> string(3) "333" }
```

Comment: thanks,i have a curl connection method and i need to  to add this line to the coption in the connection method array ```` $this->cOption[CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST] =  'PROPFIND'; ``` so i created an array called coptions in method (connection) and i need to append the line above from another method (listDirectory) to be able to list the files ..

Comment: better explained here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65554185/override-an-array-from-different-method