# override an array from different Method

Tags: php, php-curl

I would like to add an curl Option in the method listDir to be able to list the files
the connection method works just fine but when am trying to append the `cOptions` array and add        `$this->cOptions[CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST]="PROPFIND";`

it doesn work!!!! and help clue what to do?

thanks in Advance

```
<?php

class test{
   
   public static $cOptions;
   
   public function connect(){
      
      $ch = curl_init();

      $this->cOptions=array(
         CURLOPT_URL =>"111",
         CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER=>1
      );
      
      
      $response = curl_exec($ch);
      curl_close($ch);
      return $response;      
      
   }
   
   public function listDir(){
      
       $this->cOptions[CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST]="PROPFIND";
       $connection=$this->connect();
      
      return $connection; ///// should list files
   }
}
$myclass=new test();
 $myclass->connect();
$myclass->listDir();
```

Comment: Again, when you call `$this->connect();` your cURL options are set to what is defined in that `connect()` method, anything you set before it will be removed/lost/gone. Add a parameter to that `connect` method that allows you to add more cURL options

Comment: i dont want to add a parameter bcus am using this connection method in another method

Comment: You can have optional parameters ... the other method can use no parameter. Or change the way you assemble the cOptions in your `connect()` method. `$this->cOptions=...` expicitly sets the array to these values

Comment: thanks can u tell me how to write it connect(       $this->cOptions[CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST]="PROPFIND")?